# A better database design on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

In SQL Server, I need to design a `User` table. It should have a `UserID (int)`, a `RoleID (int)` and a `UserName (nvarchar(255))`.

A user can be assigned with a name but possibly multiple roles so a `UserId` may correspond to multiple `RoleID`s. This makes it difficult to assign primary key to `UserID` as `UserID` may duplicate.

Is there any better design other than breaking it up into multiple tables?

Comment: Unless you're using some weird edition of SQL Server, there's no per-table costs - why would you want to *avoid* multiple tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have:

```
1. a user table with UsertId(int), UserName (Varchar)
2. a role table with RoleId(int), RoleName(Varchar)
3. a user_role table with user_id(int), role_id(int)
```

And don't forget to add the proper indexing and foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

Ye, have a table Roles, then RolesUsers with UserID and RoleID, and lastly a Users table

edit: where the UserID + RoleID in the RolesUsers are a composite key

Comment: Thanks. In SQL Server, how to set a composite key?

Comment: Select both colums using ctrl, and press primary key icon

Comment: Didn't think it was such easy... :)

Comment: You can also add "cascade delete" on those relationships between tables so if you delete a user or roles, they get deleted in UsersRoles